# Why is the container for h1 is a lot bigger than it needs to be?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've started learning flexbox recently and tried doing some exercises to practice but I got stuck because the container for h1 is a lot bigger than it needs to be, even if margin and padding are 0, and it makes the whole other page uncentered.

[image: Image showing that container for h1 takes up all the height of the page, making the next container after it uncentered]

```css
   main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
   }

   h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
   }

   #container {
  margin-top: 100px;
   }
```

```html
   <main>
  <h1>Here are some nice pics</h1>

  <div id="container"> ... </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because default value of align-items is stretch which makes all flex items to stretch to full height of their parent. if you give align-item: flex-start to use only required height.

```css
main {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

h1 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Here are some nice pics</h1>
  <div id="container">Container</div>
</main>
```